# Compatibility of fiber formation with respect closed immersions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a proper surjective morphism between two locally Noetherian integral schemes, $Z:= V(\mathcal{I}) \subset X$ and closed subscheme of $X$ associated with quasi-coherent ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$ and $y \in Y$ ( note, I not require $y$ to be closed).

Let us denote $j: X_y \to X$ the can immersion and let $\mathcal{I}'$ be the qcoh ideal sheaf in $X_y$ obtained as *the image of* $j^*\mathcal{I}$ in $\mathcal{O}_{X_y}$ with natural map.

**Q:** What do we know about the relation between the fiber $Z_y$ and $V(\mathcal{I}') $?

Even in affine case corresponding to comparison of $(A/I) \otimes_R \kappa(y)$ with $A \otimes_R \kappa(y)$ I would guess that without any additional "regularising" assumptions -eg flatness- the answer to Q is "not much", because the formation of fibers (= certain tensorings) should behave bad with respect to ideal quotients.

But can we at least compare very "coarse" invariants of $Z_y$ and $V(\mathcal{I}') $, eg the dimensions?

Comment: They are equal.  There is a universal property of closed immersions.  That universal property shows that arbitrary pullback of a closed immersion with ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$ is a closed immersion whose ideal sheaf if the image of the pullback of $\mathcal{I}$.